# Pull lines from file with regex that is followed by phrase

Tags: regex, command-line, grep

I have an application I am working on for a client that keeps a log file of the last cron for reminder emails sent and in the log it has:

```
***************** 

app ID: 123 / app status: 0 / deposit paid: 0 /  email@domain.com 

date created: 2009-03-14 00:00:00
last updated: 1969-12-31 06:00:00pm
USING for date comparison: 2009-03-14 12:00:00am

EXPIRE THIS APP
```

I am trying to figure out how to grab the line that has `app ID: 123 / app status: 0 / deposit paid: 0 /  email@domain.com` if it is followed by `EXPIRE THIS APP` because not all of them will have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to be careful that your regex isn't too loose, or greedy matching will give false matches.  Here is a good start:

```
/(app ID: .+?)\n\ndate created: .+?\nlast updated: .+?\nUSING for date comparison: .+?\n\nEXPIRE THIS APP/
```

Comment: I would just ``grep -P /(app ID: .+?)\n\ndate created: .+?\nlast updated: .+?\nUSING for date comparison: .+?\n\nEXPIRE THIS APP/ email_reminders_detailed.log `` ? Because that gave me ``-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('``

Comment: @deth4uall:  The `(` and `)` characters have special meaning in bash, so you'd need to escape them in that context.